# Django forms how to add form field attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I want to add an attribute `http-prefix` to the outputted domain field, for example like this...

```
<input type="text" name="domain" http-prefix>
```

How is this possible? I can see crispy-forms has the ability to add css to a field `self.helper.field_class`, but I cannot see where to add an attribute to a  field like my example above just http-prefix.

**My Form:**

```
class SchemeForm(NgModelFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SchemeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'name',
        'domain',
        'slug',


    class Meta:
        model = Scheme
        fields = ('name', 'domain', 'slug')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply update the attribute by setting the value to empty string:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SchemeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #...
    self.fields['domain'].widget.attrs['http-prefix'] = ''
```