# Two Django Forms - Html page with two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, django-views

```
models.py

class ServiceRequest(models.Model):

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (None, ''),
        ('aircraft_repair', 'Aircraft Repair'),
        ('backshop', 'Backshop'),
        ('documentation', 'Documentation'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    )

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (None, ''),
        ('1', 'Level 1 - Critical'),  # <24 hours
        ('2', 'Level 2 - Urgent'),  # 1-2 days
        ('3', 'Level 3 - Standard'),  # 3-4 days
        ('4', 'Level 4 - Low')  # 5+ days
    )

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    request_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=number)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=None)
    due_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Due Date', auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default='3')  # default to standard priority
    aircraft = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    NrcWorkOrder = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Work Order')
    NrcZone = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Zone')
    NrcItem = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Item')
    EgWorkOrder = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    EgZone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    EgItem = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    references = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    attachments = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.request_number  # show the request number in admin screen

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-request_number',)  # sort request number descending in admin screen


class File(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(verbose_name="Attachments", name="files", upload_to="files/", blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.files

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('file_list')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.files.delete()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
forms.py

class ServiceRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceRequest

        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'contact',
            'category',
            'due_date',
            'aircraft',
            'NrcWorkOrder',
            'NrcZone',
            'NrcItem',
            'references',
            'description',
            'request_number',  # TODO remove before switching to production mode - should be hidden
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #  self.fields['attachments'].widget.attrs.update({'input type': 'file', 'name': 'files', 'multiple': True})
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('first_name', css_class='input-large'),
                Column('last_name', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
            Row(
                Column('email', css_class='input-large'),
                Column('contact', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
            Row(
                 Column('category', css_class='input-large'),
                 Column('aircraft', css_class='input-large'),
                 Column('due_date', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
            Row(
                Column('NrcWorkOrder', css_class='input-large'),
                Column('NrcZone', css_class='input-large'),
                Column('NrcItem', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
            Row(
                Column('references', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
            Row(
                Column('description', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
            Row(
                 Column('request_number', css_class='input-large'),
            ),
        )


class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['files']
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.esr_submit, name='esr_submit'),
    path('files/', views.file_list, name='file_list'),
    path('files/<int:pk>/', views.delete_file, name='delete_file'),
]
```

```
views.py

def delete_file(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = File.objects.get(pk=pk)
        file.delete()
    return redirect('file_list')

def file_list(request):
    files = File.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('file_list')
    else:
        form = FileForm()
    return render(request, 'esr_submit/file_list.html', {
        'files': files,
        'form': form
    })

def esr_submit(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        initial_data = {'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                        'last_name': request.user.last_name,
                        'email': request.user.email,
                        'contact': request.user.phone,
                        }
        request_form = ServiceRequestForm(initial=initial_data)
        file_form = FileForm()
    else:
        request_form = ServiceRequestForm()
        file_form = FileForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # request_form = ServiceRequestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if 'file_upload' in request.POST:
            file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if file_form.is_valid():
                file_form.save()
                # return redirect('esr_submit')

    return render(request, 'esr_submit/esr_submit.html', {'request_form': request_form, 'file_form': file_form})
```

```
esr_submit.html

{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Submit an ESR
{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<head>

</head>
<br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-8 mb-4 shadow-lg p-3 bg-white rounded">
                <div class="header mb-2">
                    <h3 class="header mb-0 text-center">New Engineering Service Request</h3>
                    {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <small class="text-muted"><strong>Want to speed things up? </strong><a href="/login/?next=/esr_submit/"> Log In |</a></small>
                        <small class="text-muted"><a href="/register/?next=/esr_submit/">Create an account </a></small>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="request_form">
                    <div class="col">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% crispy request_form %}

                    </div>
                </form>
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file_upload">
                    <div class="col">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ file_form|crispy }}
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="pl-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="file_upload" value="file&upload" form="file_upload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_request" value="submit&request" class="btn btn-primary" form="request_form">Submit Request</button>
                    <button type="button" name="#" value="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save Draft</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content%}
```

I have a function based view with two forms. The first form collects request information, the second form collects any files the user "attaches" to the request. There is a File Upload Button (to save the file to the database), Submit Request Button (to post the request), and a Save Draft (to save a draft of the request to the database).

Below are the challenges that I have spent a week with no luck. Note: I started learning Python and Django in March 2020, so I am pushing my knowledge base as I develop this project.

My challenges:

1. If there is no file selected when the Upload File button is clicked, I need to notify the user that no file has been selected - without losing any data typed into the request form.
2. Currently, when the Upload File button is clicked, the page refreshes. I do not want to lose any data typed into the request form. How do I stop this from happening?
3. Each time a file is uploaded, I need it to show the file link at the bottom of the request form, without losing any data typed into the request form.
4. How do I save a draft of the request form in the event not all required fields are populated?

Comment: Have you considered using front-end validation with JavaScript?

Comment: Hello Arthur - I am very novice with JavaScript. Do you have a recommended article/link that I can read up on this topic?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvcORaD1MoI This looks promising

Comment: Arthur - how do I add the onfocusout attribute if I am developing the form using crispy forms (see forms.py)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999795/django-forms-how-to-add-form-field-attribute so it would be: self.fields["FIELD"].widget.attrs["autofocus"]=""